# Upgrade ASP.NET Web Form project to latest Web Form project

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I have an existing (ancient) ASP.NET Web Form project that I want to upgrade to latest ASP.NET Web Form.

Is there any tutorial/ tool that can help me out in this migration.

Comment: have you tried just compiling your project in a more up to date framework version?

Comment: @Kritner it works but I want to use the new template that have built in bundling and magnification etc...

Comment: what's stopping you from doing that?  First result in google for "bundling and minification webforms" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx

Comment: @Kritner I did what you asked and I am getting the following errors:  'ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.'